# react I want console.log() to be displayed when I scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to display console.log() when the list is scrolled to the bottom.
The following code does not show console.log() when scrolling to the bottom of the list.
Also, const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } will show an error.
error message
The property 'scrollTop' does not exist for type 'undefined'. ts(2339)
The property 'scrollHeight' does not exist for type 'undefined'. ts(2339)
The property 'clientHeight' does not exist for type 'undefined'. ts(2339)

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
const Test: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const listInnerRef = useRef();

  const onScroll = () => {
    if (listInnerRef.current) {
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = listInnerRef.current;
      if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
        // TO SOMETHING HERE
        console.log('Reached bottom');
      }
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className="list">
        <div className="list-inner" onScroll={onScroll} ref={listInnerRef}>
          <ul>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li className="height-100">aaaaaaaa</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can subtract the scrolled height from the total scrollable height.
2. If this is equal to the visible area, you are at the bottom `element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight`
3. In react, just add an onScroll listener to the scrollable element, and use `event.target` in the callback.

```
 
 

     function handleScroll(event) {
        var node = event.target;
        const bottom = node.scrollHeight - node.scrollTop === node.clientHeight;
        if (bottom) {
            console.log('BOTTOM REACHED:', bottom);
         }
       }
```

Comment: Where do I call the above process?
Can I get rid of the onScroll process?